# Using icons in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to add icons to my toolbar buttons in extJS. In my case, i want a refresh icon in my button.

Is there an *easy* and *standard* way of doing this? I can't seem to be able to find any decent documentation on the web.

My toolbar button :

```
{
            text: 'Reset',
            icon: 'refresh',
            tooltip: 'Reset Grid Layout'
}
```

putting refresh here doesn't do anything. There is an empty space in my button where something should be. Ie. it understands 'icon', it doesn't understand 'refresh'.

- Do you have to put in the full path to some ExtJS subdirectory?
- Is there some set list of icons you can use?

Comment: I think that if you change icon:'refresh' to 
iconCls : 'x-tbar-loading'. you will get what you want, I predefined refresh icon .

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `iconCls:` and provide a css class that sets the proper `background` set, along with other information (size, color, etc)
2. You can use `icon:` and pass a relative path to your image.
3. There are `glyphs` of which I don't know much, but there are some good examples on the web (e.g. [this](http://senchado.blogspot.gr/2014/01/glyphs-in-ext42.html)). Basically you load an icon font and set the character code in the `glyph:` config of the button.
4. And finally there are some really nice icons for panel header, named: `tools`. The default theme can be seen [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool-cfg-type). The Neptune ones are much nicer. Check the [Kitchen Sink examples](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/).
   (if you find their class names you can use them anywhere with some tweaking). 
   Those are defined in your panel `config`.

Example:

```
config: {
  ...., 
  tools: [
    {type: 'refresh'},
    {type: 'save'}, 
    ...]  
},
```

More information at [the official documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tools).

Answer (score 2):

I belive ExtJS or Ext.NET tends to use the fam fam fam silk icon set.

http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

Typically to use icons on things like buttons, set a css class which points to you icon location e.g.

```
.myIcon {
    background-image: url(path of your image);
}
```

The on your Ext component you can set the relevant property. This could be `iconCls: ''` or something similar (depends on the component).

Answer (score 1):

I did what the @dougajmcdonald recommended.

In my **ext-all.css** underneath this line :

```
@import '../ext-theme-gray/ext-theme-gray-all.css';
```

I added my icon paths :

```
.myIcon {
    background-image: url('../ext-theme-gray/images/grid/columns.gif');
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best pattern of doing things with icons. There might be a simpler way because I have to use 'ext-theme-gray' for all the URLs. When I change look and feel, then every URL has to be updated. Perhaps there is a way of defining variables in CSS that would take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't find in docs something related to default extjs icons usage for tabs.
>   But you can define your custom icon css using **iconCls** config.

```
{
   title: 'Foo',
   iconCls:'refreshIconCls'
}
```

CSS:

```
.refreshIconCls{
   background-image:url(../images/refresh.png)!important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of icons but only for type **Ext.panel.Tool**. See API [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool). It is used using config option **type**

For, normal buttons, you need to give paths to your image file

Ext.button also has type, but that is not for icons. See [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
   {
     xtype:'button',
     iconCls:'fa fa-bars',
   }
   //fa fa-bars is the link from the icon source, fa fa-bars represents bars icon, try this example in your code for show the icon
```

You can get more icon types from http://fontawesome.io/icons/